# Canvas only saves part of image and stretches it out weirdly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I've successfully managed to work with canvases before, but the same code I've used before is suddenly only drawing part of the image.

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/o04zaamn/)

HTML:

```
<canvas id="card-texture-canvas"></canvas>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/VaN8wBY.png" id="background">
<button class="save">Save</button>
```

JS:

```
$('.save').click(function () {
    var d_canvas = document.getElementById('card-texture-canvas')
    var context = d_canvas.getContext('2d')
    var background = document.getElementById('background')
    context.drawImage(background, 0, 0)
    $('#background').hide()
})
```

And with CSS I force it to be the correct width and height:

```
#card-texture-canvas {
    height: 297px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

But the drawing of the image completely disregards that and instead saves the top-right part of the image, stretches it out to a weird ratio (300x150; still not what I try to establish in the CSS), and leaves it at that...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Standard canvas size is 150x100 and CSS will **stretch** it to the desired size, but it still has 150x100 drawing dots on it, so you must set its size inline

```
<canvas width="297" height="200"></canvas>
```

or using javascript:

```
document.getElementById('card-texture-canvas').width = 297
document.getElementById('card-texture-canvas').height = 200
```

Comment: Weird. This has never been the case before. They must have changed it for some reason. Thanks!